# Discord bot not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

I have put the .env file and .py file in the same directory,
using this code:

```
import os

os.mkdir('Mindful_Bot/')
print("New directory created!")

import shutil
shutil.move('MindfulBot', 'Mindful_Bot/')
'Mindful_Bot'

print("MindfulBot folder was moved into the directory 'Mindful_Bot'")
```

I have removed the quotes, yet I still can't get this bot to connect to discord. Instead, I get this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amber\AppData\local-packages\Python39\Meme_Bot\MemeBot\meme_bot.py", line 8, in <module>
    TOKEN = os.getenv(DISCORD_TOKEN)
NameError: name 'DISCORD_TOKEN' is not defined
```

My code is as follows:

meme_bot.py code

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv(DISCORD_TOKEN)

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

.env.py code

`DISCORD_TOKEN = "discord token here"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Don't leak your token!

Comment: Ack! I forgot to get rid of that thank you! Don't worry the toke is regenerated :)

Comment: Use environment variables. Not `.env.py`.

Comment: how do I make a variable file then? I made one called .env and it listed it as a .py file :(

Comment: See [how to set an env variable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html)

Comment: I have set a variable using the file .env.py in advanced settings, but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the quotation marks. [`os.getenv()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv) takes a string as argument.

```
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
```